# Polyfit Function with Stock Prices from yfinance

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, approximation

i have the following issue to solve:
I want to download stockdata from yfinance and store that into a dataframe.

Then, instead of just plotting the data via matplotlib i additionally want to approximate the movement of that chart with a polynomial function, in order to be able to perform the derivatives of that function and apply some analysis.

Therefore i thought it might a solution to apply the polyfit function and feed the stock data into that.

Please let me know, if there would be a more appropiate solution to my goal. This is what i can conclude so far.

Going with my approach, i came up with this Code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

stock = 'TSLA'
start = '2020-11-01'

df = yf.download(stock , start=start)

x_data = df.index
y_data = df['Close']

xx = np.asarray(x_data).astype(int)
yy = np.asarray(y_data).astype(int)

x = np.linspace(200, 15.0, 200)

# polynomial fit of degree 7
p7 = np.polyfit(xx, yy, 7)
y_p7 = np.polyval(p7, x)

#plotting
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'o')
plt.plot(x, y_p7, ':')
plt.ylim(0.,1200)

plt.legend(['data', 'polyfit7'])
plt.show()
```

However what comes out when i run this, is the following plot:
[image: polyfit approach]

This might come, because the Polyfitfunction dont know how to interprete the converted timestamp dates.

In this sense, i thought i could be a solution to connect the days (datetime) to simple and uprising integers (numbers) starting from 1 up and ongoing.

What are your thoughts on this? should i use another approach or can i fix this one?

Best wishes and many thanks,
Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

The approach of converting timestamp dates to integers works fine, you just need to match the x-coordinates sample points used in the fit with the `polyval` step. Here I'm using `min` and `max` to obtain the full range of dates used in the `polyfit`. For the plot you can then convert the dates back using [`astype('datetime64[ns]')`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

```py
...
xx = np.asarray(x_data).astype(int)
yy = np.asarray(y_data).astype(int)

x = np.linspace(min(xx), max(xx), 200)
# polynomial fit of degree 7
p7 = np.polyfit(xx, yy, 7)
y_p7 = np.polyval(p7, x)

#plotting
plt.plot(xx.astype('datetime64[ns]'), yy, 'o')
plt.plot(x.astype('datetime64[ns]'), y_p7, '.', ms=4)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend(['data', 'polyfit7'])
plt.show()
```

[image: polyfit_stock_prices]